# traditional rails commands don't work with ruby 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line-interface, ruby-2.3

I updated my ruby version to 2.3, and now when I try simple commands like `rails new myApp` I have this error message:

```
rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.1.2
  2.2.2
```

Can you please help me with that, I can't find any answer online :)

Comment: did you install rails for ruby 2.3?

Comment: I installed rails 5 on a local path for a specific app that uses it, do I need to install it globally ?

Comment: you have to have rails executable in your PATH

Answer (score 0):

Just install rails on new ruby version with:

`$ gem install rails`